# Heat transfer with tie constraint

Tags: abaqus

I am doing heat conduction between rock and a thin rod inside the rock. High Temperature is applied on thin rod to model heat conduction in the rock. I am using beam element B31 for thin rod and C3D8PT for rock. and I am using tie constraint to tie thin rod into rock.

I applied temperature boundary condition to thin rod. Why there is no any temperature result from either thin rod and rock? Could you please help me point the potential error? I am wondering if it is possible to apply temperature boundary condition to tied element?

Thank you so much

** Constraint: tie
*Tie, name=tie, adjust=yes
s_Surf-1, m_Surf-1

** BOUNDARY CONDITIONS
**
** Name: BC-T Type: Temperature
*Boundary
Set-rod, 11, 11, 300.

Comment: Have you asked explicitly  for temperature output for your Step? Also, you can try with contact and no separation, just to verify if it behaves in the same way.

Comment: Thanks Roman. Yes I did. I found a similar post before. It says embedded constraint doesn’t have temperature DOF, and suggest to use solid element? Can you confirm it? Thanks https://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=464475

Comment: See "Limitations" paragraph in the [documentation](http://localhost:2080/v6.14/books/usb/default.htm?startat=pt08ch35s04aus136.html): _"Rotational, temperature, pore pressure, acoustic pressure, and electrical potential degrees of freedom at an embedded node are not constrained"_

Comment: Thanks Roman, when it says temperatures DOF are not constrained, what does it mean? Does it means there are no temperature DOF for the embedded element or temperature at the imbedded element cannot be transferred to host? Thanks

Comment: From my understanding (I've never worked with embedded elements) if embedded nodes are constrained in displacement DOFs by the surrounding mesh, it means that there is the interaction between and the displacement is restricted. Apparently, the same is not applicable for temperature DOF

Comment: Thanks Roman, good to have you here.

Comment: @roudan do you have a good documentation on C3D8PT element? e.g. its PDEs and asusmptions.